# WPF ComboBox twoway databinding is not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have an `Products` object with many properties. One of them is as follows

```
    class Products : DependencyObject
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(IDProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IDProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(int), typeof(Products), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(IDChanged)));

        private static void IDChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"New ID {e.NewValue}");
        }
    }
```

I have bound it with my combobox `selecteditem` property. The combobox `itemsource` is populated by a separate function which provides a list of Product IDs. As the IDs are not known initially it is set to default 0 at first.

The binding is done as follows

```
private void testClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Products products = new Products();
            ProductListCombobox.ItemsSource = GetProductIDList();
            ProductListCombobox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding { Source = items, Path = new PropertyPath(Products.IDProperty), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Converter = new ProductsIDConverter(), ConverterParameter = ProductListCombobox });
        }
```

The `converter` class for the binding

```
        class ProductsIDConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var id = (int)value;
                var cmb = (ComboBox)parameter;
                if (!cmb.Items.Contains(id)) return cmb.Items[0];
                else return id;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Here in the `converter` class I set the first value of the items list to be the `selecteditem` which in turn should update the ID property on the source too as it is two way binding as far as I know. But it does not update the property back. But it updates if I manually change the `selecteditem`. I am pretty new to this databinding thing so if anyone cares to give some solution here will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: The value returned from the `Convert` is not supposed to update the source property. It sets the target property.

Comment: so how do I update my source then? it needs to be updated with the target property

Comment: You bind to the source. That's the point of using a binding...The source defines the values that you display in the view. When/How/Why do you want to update the source?

Comment: the combobox is used to take user inputs. also it it used to show the current value of the object. that's why I used twoway binding

Comment: User input as selecting an existing value? If not, you need to write custom code.